# Date difference for each customer and product in R

Tags: r, aggregate

```
custid <- c(1,2,2,2) 

prod <- c("books", "highlighters", "books", "pens" )

qdate <- c(20130401,  20130403, 20130403, 20130404) 

tdate <- c(20130405,  20130804, 20130405, 20130405)

data <- data.frame(custid, prod, qdate, tdate)

  data$qdate <- as.Date(as.character(data$qdate), "%Y%m%d") 
  data$tdate <- as.Date(as.character(data$tdate), "%Y%m%d") 

(data2 <- difftime(data$tdate, data$qdate, data$custid, units="days")) #works

data2 <- aggregate(cbind(data$tdate=format(date, '%Y-%m-%d'))~cbind(data$qdate=format(date, '%Y-%m-%d'))  + data$prod + data$custid, data, difftime(data$tdate, data$qdate, data$custid, units="days"))
```

For the R code above, I am trying to use aggregate function to find the output like below. The difftime gives the days difference correctly. However, the aggregate functions is not working and causing errors. Does any body know how to fix this issue? Thanks.

```
custid  prod            qdate       tdate       days_difference
1       books           20130401    20130405    4
2       highlighters    20130403    20130804    123
2       books           20130403    20130405    2
2       pens            20130404    20130405    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your can make this so much simpler by beginning to use `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
custid <- c(1,2,2,2) 

prod <- c("books", "highlighters", "books", "pens" )

# ymd = year, month, day
qdate <- ymd(c(20130401,  20130403, 20130403, 20130404))

tdate <- ymd(c(20130405,  20130804, 20130405, 20130405))

data <- data.frame(custid, prod, qdate, tdate)
data$days_difference <- with(data, difftime(tdate, qdate, units="days"))
data
  custid         prod      qdate      tdate days_difference
1      1        books 2013-04-01 2013-04-05          4 days
2      2 highlighters 2013-04-03 2013-08-04        123 days
3      2        books 2013-04-03 2013-04-05          2 days
4      2         pens 2013-04-04 2013-04-05          1 days
```

**EDIT**

If you don't want 'days' in the column use `as.numeric`

```
data$days_difference <- as.numeric(with(data, difftime(tdate, qdate, custid, units="days")))
  custid         prod      qdate      tdate days_difference
1      1        books 2013-04-01 2013-04-05               4
2      2 highlighters 2013-04-03 2013-08-04             123
3      2        books 2013-04-03 2013-04-05               2
4      2         pens 2013-04-04 2013-04-05               1
```

Comment: Both cdeterman and @Richard Scriven works. Thanks guys so much. In the days_difference column, how do I not include "days"?

Comment: Just use `as.numeric`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `aggregate()` for a row-wise calculation. You can use the unary `-` operator on "Date" classed objects. Wrap it in `c()` to remove the "difftime" class.

```
within(data, day_diff <- c(tdate - qdate))
#   custid         prod      qdate      tdate day_diff
# 1      1        books 2013-04-01 2013-04-05        4
# 2      2 highlighters 2013-04-03 2013-08-04      123
# 3      2        books 2013-04-03 2013-04-05        2
# 4      2         pens 2013-04-04 2013-04-05        1
```